# How to make Visual Studio Code show really all TypeScript type errors?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In my TypeScript/React project, "react-scripts start" shows type errors that are not shown inline in my Visual Studio Code IDE.
Most types errors are actually shown inline, but not all.
What could be the reason for that? How can I make Visual Studio Code show all errors directly?

VS Code setting "typescript.validate.enable" is set to true

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ....
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is the solution to your issue, but for me I often get issues like the ones you're describing when VSCODE is running on a different version than your build is.

Down in the right corner, you can select which version you want to use in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

Simply click the version number (3.0.3 in image) and select the version from your workspace instead of the latest installed in vscode!