# why nodejs + babelrc + flow gives me a error on visual studio?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, babeljs

i got a problem.
I'm developping my api with nodejs and babel to get the ES6 format.
But when I want to use @flow inside my files I got a problem.

For example, if I do so :

```
export const DBNAME: string = "qsdqsd";
```

Visual studio is telling me that there is an error but of course when i run flow or when I compile with babel there is no error. How can I do to avoid this problem ?

thanks

Comment: Visual studio or visual studio code?

Comment: Possibly something similar to [this, if vscode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119113/how-to-make-visual-studio-code-show-really-all-typescript-type-errors/55119485#55119485) Basically, your IDE is running its own linting, which will help you to see errors before building. But the linting is not synced with your build configuration.

Comment: Hello its visual studio code !

Comment: And was my other comment the solution?